# How to run Specflow test using Tags in from command line in .net core

Tags: .net-core, nunit, specflow

How to run Specflow test using Tags in from command line in  .net core

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: I am using NUNIT Provider

Answer (score 2):

With .NET Core, you have the `dotnet test` command available to you. Tags in SpecFlow become `[TestCategory]` attributes in the .feature.cs file parsed from your feature file. You should be able to run SpecFlow tests by tag using the TestCategory filter:

```
dotnet test path\to\project.csproj --filter:"TestCategory=SpecFlowTag"
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details

Alternatively, NUnit comes with its own command line tool:

```
nunit3-console path\to\tests.dll --where "cat == SpecFlowTag"
```

More info:

- https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html
- https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Test-Selection-Language.html